# bitnami mean does not work using bitnami script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bitnami, forever

Im using bitnami 3.2.11-0, when I try to start serivce something bad occurs and neither service could be started.

```
    root@ip-172-31-15-96:/home/bitnami/apps/api# sudo service bitnami start
    resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
    The filesystem is already 26212055 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

    /opt/bitnami/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh : mongodb could not be started
    /opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm could not be started
    Syntax OK
    (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
    (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
    no listening sockets available, shutting down
    AH00015: Unable to open logs
    /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started

    /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_update_ip: 17: /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_update_ip: /opt/bitnami/apps/*/bnconfig: not found
    daemon with PID 1454 awakened
```

```
    ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
    about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    forked process: 1559
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.815+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1559 port=27017 dbpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-15-96
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.11
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { filePermissions: 502, pathPrefix: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp" } }$
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.842+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2017-10-09T21:33:01.842+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=sn$
    2017-10-09T21:33:02.088+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (1) [1507584782:87985][1559:0x7fb7a2216cc0], file:collection-51-8988087643268075125.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/collection-51-898808764326807$
    2017-10-09T21:33:02.088+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: 1: Operation not permitted at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 79
    2017-10-09T21:33:02.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
     0x1313f62 0x12be9c8 0x12a6ced 0x10910e4 0x108f9e0 0x108ba02 0x108a40d 0x107afbb 0xfda4b4 0xfe0252 0x1079838 0xf9d4c8 0x96270e 0x964cb0 0x967ebd 0x7fb7a1117f45 0x95f0c9
    ----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
    {"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F13F62","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"EBE9C8","s":"_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc"},{"b":"400000","o":"EA6CED","s":"_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j"},{"b":"400000",$
     mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x1313f62]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x138) [0x12be9c8]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j+0xAD) [0x12a6ced]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo17WiredTigerSession9getCursorERKSsmb+0xE4) [0x10910e4]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo16WiredTigerCursorC1ERKSsmbPNS_16OperationContextE+0x50) [0x108f9e0]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStore6CursorC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKS0_b+0x92) [0x108ba02]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStoreC1EPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_SsbbllPNS_14CappedCallbackEPNS_20WiredTigerSizeStorerE+0x3ED) [0x108a40d]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine14getRecordStoreEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_RKNS_17CollectionOptionsE+0x1AB) [0x107afbb]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo22KVDatabaseCatalogEntry14initCollectionEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsb+0x204) [0xfda4b4]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo15KVStorageEngineC1EPNS_8KVEngineERKNS_22KVStorageEngineOptionsE+0x6D2) [0xfe0252]
     mongod(+0xC79838) [0x1079838]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x598) [0xf9d4c8]
     mongod(+0x56270E) [0x96270e]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x10) [0x964cb0]
     mongod(main+0x15D) [0x967ebd]
     libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7fb7a1117f45]
     mongod(+0x55F0C9) [0x95f0c9]
    -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
    2017-10-09T21:33:02.097+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

    ***aborting after invariant() failure


    ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
```

If I try using bin command it'll run.

```
    root@ip-172-31-15-96:/home/bitnami/apps/api# mongod            
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15830 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-15-96
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.11
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.572+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.572+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.724+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.725+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.725+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
    2017-10-09T19:13:48.725+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Please don't post images of logs.  Post the logs themselves.

Comment: Logs was posted as plain text, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've reinstalled bitnami mean stack using wget.

`$ wget https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/159963/bitnami-meanstack-3.4.9-0-linux-x64-installer.run`

`$ chmod +x ./bitnami-meanstack-3.4.9-0-linux-x64-installer.run`

I followed the installer steps and then run `$ sudo service bitnami start mongodb`.

Thanks.

Comment: please add more description and steps that you have followed, if this step leads any issue then make sure you must have to pointing out here.

Answer (score 0):

In bitnami stacks the following script is used:

```
   sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

I advise you to use that one but like this

```
   sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Comment: Thanks, bitnami service run those commands and I got the first log.